# jQuery Fancybox 2.0.1 + Modal Mode

Tags: jquery, plugins, fancybox

I am unable to get Fancybox to not close when a user clicks on the overlay. I cannot seem to find options for Modal mode like there was in 1.3, so I am trying to replicate it using existing options. Is there a way to prevent the box from closing when the user clicks on the Overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'closeClick' : false
```

That should do it. For more information on available properties/API, see http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
modal: true // by default its false
closeClick: false
hideOnOverlayClick: false
hideOnContentClick: false

//check for reference: http://fancybox.net/api
```

Hope it helps